# JavaScript navbar opening

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do javascript navbar but for some reason can't get it to work. I inspected those elements on the browser, but when I click the open button elements don't get those classes. Could somebody check out what is my problem?

Here's my Javascript:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".main-menu");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".open-button");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

openButton.onClick = () => {
    navbar.classList.add("show");
    openButton.classList.add("hide");
    body.classList.add("disabled");
};

closeButton.onClick = () => {
    body.classList.remove("disabled");
    navbar.classList.remove("show");
    openButton.classList.remove("hide");
};
```

Comment: Could you also share the CSS?

Comment: Did you try adding a `console.log("test!");` into the events, just to try out if they get called at all? You could try using `openButton.addEventListener("click", () => { ... });` instead of immediately assigning the function.

Comment: Typo: the property name is `onclick` not `onClick`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery instead for that simply DOM Manipulations, which is a framework of Javascript. Using Jquery makes your code more readable and shorter than vanilla javascript.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
            $("#openButton").click(()=>{
                $("body").toggleClass("disabled");
                $("#closeButton").toggleClass("hide");
                $(".main-menu").toggleClass("show");
            });
        });
```